# read e-books in Emacs

Tags: pdf, docview

I use eww to read online articles in Emacs instead of in a browser because it is less distracting and I can take notes in an org-mode quickly without switching applications.

I wonder how feasible it is to read an e-books in epub, or pdf format in Emacs? I found the epubmode.el on emacswiki.org but it is broken and haven't been updated since 2011.

Comment: Opening PDF should work out of the box.

Comment: And the pdf-tools package makes them look and behave even better. At this point I'm frustrated using anything else.

Answer (score 10):

Try [nov](https://github.com/wasamasa/nov.el) (installable via melpa). It is a reasonable start for reading ePUBs in Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

`.epub` are in fact `.zip` file with `.xhtml` file inside. You can just open them, find the .xhtml file that has the content (often content.html), and open it. Then you can call `shr-render-buffer` to display the html.

This do not solve several problem:

- finding automatically the correct .xhtml
- use the table of content,
- bigger epub have several .xhtml (say, one by chapter), one need a way to go from one to the next.

Comment: `shr-render-buffer` is great! I can go though all the xhtml files and convert all to a single org file, based on the table of content. thanks!

Comment: I don't seem to have `shr-render-buffer` in emacs 24.3? It also looks like someone started to make an `epub-mode`, but I was unable to get that working either: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EpubMode

Comment: Ah... I had to load `shr` with `load-library`.  Still not working very well though! A real, working `epub-mode` would be nice.

Comment: The emacspeak package has a mode for reading epub files in eww. I use it all the time. You won't want the whole emacspeak package, but you should be able to use how it does this as a way to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [emacs-ereader](https://github.com/bddean/emacs-ereader). My experience is that it errs out less often while parsing an epub than nov and it too is installable as a package. Further, it supports annotations, integrates decent with Org, in a slightly more primitive way than the awesome pdf-tools does for PDFs.

Comment: FYI, invalid EPUBs are *not* supported in nov.el. If you run into a valid EPUB still triggering errors, please report a bug and send me the file via email or so.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT
Actually this answer seems more useful than presumed initially. I only tried this method on one book, and that book's conversion looked bad. I have tried multiple other books now, and most look reasonably well after conversion. Still, it might be possible to make the conversion look even better using mutool its epub/css config options.
END EDIT

Although maybe not a very useful answer here, I still like to inform about the following possibility.

Emacs comes with doc-view-mode already. If you have the `mutool` command available on your system then Emacs doc-view-mode will use it to convert pdf's to png.
Now mutool is also able to convert epub to png. So by making doc-view to recognize an epub as a pdf, i.e. add `("epub" pdf)` to the pdf options in the `doc-view-set-doc-type` function, you can read an epub by opening your epub file and then switch to doc-view-mode. The conversion takes some time, and it takes a while (~30sec) before the png image will appear.

Now I tried this succesfully myself, but the converted document did not look great. However, the `mutool draw` command offers some configuration options for epub conversion. Unfortunately I do not understand these options well yet, as mutool tells me the following when using a very simple css stylesheet.

```
error: css syntax error: expected keyword in property (content/stylesheet.css:3)
```

Maybe someone who understands mupdf or css or epub could comment on this answer for how to get a nice epub conversion with mutool. Then doc-view-mode might be another nice option for reading epubs (and a feature request could be opened for official epub support in doc-view-mode).

Comment: That's a clever idea! Perhaps you should ask about the problem with css styling with mutool, as a separate question, though?

Comment: @aplaice Thanks! I agree that the css styling question might be better asked separately, but also I figured that many people here know css or epub well and someone here might be able to answer it. I am not very familiar with css nor with epub. I have edited the answer btw, because most books look much better than the one I tried first.